# Qt HTTP request sending DELETE with Data

Tags: c++, qt

rest API:
someting/post expects 'token' as bytearray body data
something/delete expects 'token' as bytearray body data

Using Qt I can prepare the data in a QByteArray and send via deleteResource (that doesn't accepts a data parameter) and I can use sendCustomRequest that accepts a data parameter, but if I use the later with DELETE I have no data.

With POST, I do have the data.

Minimal code example, python server - just to exemplify. the Qt code is below.:

```
@route('/something/delete', "DELETE")
def somethingDelete(url, post):
    print(post) # empty

@route('/something/delete2', "POST")
def somethingDelete2(url, post):
    print(post) # correct output.
```

and the Qt code that triggers the server calls - This code is higly shortened to simplify, but the idea is that.

```
QNetworkRequest req;
req.setRawHeader("OCS-APIREQUEST", "true");
req.setUrl = Utility::concatUrlPath(account()->url(), path());
QByteArray bufferData("token=" + _token);
sendCustomRequest(req, "POST", bufferData);
```

as soon as I change the POST to DELETE, I don't get the token, but the correct python function is executed.

Comment: Have you used something like wireshark to see if it is the request that does not send the token or if it is the Python server that discards it?

Comment: python server doesn't discards it because other clients written in different toolkits trigger the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The DELETE HTTP verb does not have a request body so your buffer is probably simply dropped by Qt. To use DELETE you would need to encode your token in the URL.

Comment: That's a moot point: the server expects a DELETE with body data, I know that in the mozila-developer documentation DELETE do not accepts data, but a lot of http-based API relies on that. And I won't be able to fix all of thosen broken http-apis, so I need a way to send data with a delete. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE

Comment: It's not moot if support for it is sporadic. Did you check that your data is in the body with Wireshark as others already suggested?

Answer (score 0):

As of Qt 5.9.2, it seems that Qt might ignore body data when performing a `DELETE` operation.

In Qt code in `QNetworkReplyHttpImplPrivate::postRequest()`, one can see that `createUploadByteDevice()` is not called when the operation is `QNetworkAccessManager::DeleteOperation`.

However, this is only valid when the `DELETE` request is sent by calling `QNetworkAccessManager::deleteResource()`, which is the only way to create a network request with the `QNetworkAccessManager::DeleteOperation` operation. Also note that this function does not allow you to send any body data.

If you use `QNetworkAccessManager::sendCustomRequest()` to send the request, then as far as Qt is concerned the operation is `QNetworkAccessManager::CustomOperation`. The custom `verb` you pass is not processed further, and Qt will behave exactly the same whatever the value of `verb` is. Even if `verb` is a known value like `POST` or `DELETE`.
This means that Qt does not discard the body data.

So if you used `QNetworkAccessManager::sendCustomRequest()`, as you claim, your body data is sent to the server (confirmed by Wireshark). So the issue is not on Qt side, but on the server side.

Comment: then I have no idea what the hell happened :) as the iOS and Android client can call the method, and the Qt one cant. I created a tiny patch on the server to allow the delete operation to receive another parameter.